# Connecting to bluetooth accessory with iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

Can I use GameKit to send data from an iPhone to an accessory, and if not is there some other way to connect without joining the Made for iPhone program

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bluetooth to connect to other iPhone/iPod devices, but other than that you need the Made for iPhone program.

Even if it was technically possible, your app would be rejected if you tried it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Bump (the app) can connect an iphone and an android phone via bluetooth... I'd guess they used the gamekit for that